# Create two 'Bars' of color with CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with some (Bootstrap) CSS. Right now, I'm retexturing the navbar. This is the CSS for the section I am working on.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #transparent;
}
```

I am working specifically on the background section. I want to draw a band of color at the top, and then have transparency (or another color) beneath. Unlike a gradient, I do not want these to  blend. I created this mockup in Photoshop (the black represents the part that I want transparent, if possible).

[Mockup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2fH9.png)

Comment: Do you want the content to go under top band or start in bottom and end in top?

Comment: Under. In the black area.

Comment: In that case, you want to set  `border-top`, as Duver suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but try adding a border top:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #transparent;
    border-top: 3px solid #FF9900;
}
```

Comment: Achieves the desired effect, but is there any way to avoid the extra space it adds to the top of the navbar?